# Socket programming between two networks

Tags: android, sockets, wifi

I want to connect two devices using socket. The devices may or maynot be in the same networks. It may be connected using wifi or mobile networks. Is it possible? If this is not the right way, how can I connect two devices without using server?

Comment: Using wifi and both devices having internet connection then it is possible if routers are configured properly to forward used ports. Using mobile there are chances that the mobile provider does not want you to do so.

Comment: This also depends on the protocol you will be using. Not every protocol will be routed. "*Using socket*" does not imply a specific protocol.